# What's the use of a label on a deployment in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

In the book [Kubernetes: Up & Running](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26759355-kubernetes), on the section "Creating Deployments", it has a yaml file that starts like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels: 
    run: nginx
```

What is the use of applying a label to a deployment? I understand how the pods and a service interact, but when do the labels in a deployment spring into action?

Answer (score 2):

Labels are useful to group inter-related apps. For example, you have a application that require a Deployment, a Service, a Database(maybe deployed with deployment or statefulset). Now,if you use similar labels to all these resources(let it is `app: my-app`), then you can list,delete etc. operation based on this label.

For example, if you want to list all resources for your particular application, then you can use `kubectl get all -l app=my-app`.

For more details, please read this [article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/).